# Как мигать светодиодами на контроллере Cortex-M3 на Ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Использую для программирования Keil uVision, где синтаксис отличается от обычного, и я вроде переписал программу под Cortex-M3, и он даже не выдаёт ошибок, но при этом ничего не горит вообще. Я подозреваю, что дело в неверных адресах, а может я что-то не дописал и не понял.
И сразу скажу, что мне нужно написать именно на Ассемблере, именно чтобы светились светодиоды, и желательно с миганием. Задание в универе такое.

Вот код, который я использовал:

```
AREA MyData, DATA
AREA MYCODE, CODE
    ENTRY
    EXPORT main
main
   LDR R0, =0x20001000  
   LDR R1, =0x18   
   STR R1, [R0]      
   LDR R1, [R0]
   ORR R1, R1, #0x04
   STR R1, [R0]         
   MOV R2, #0x100000   
delay
   SUBS R2, R2, #1     
   BNE delay       
   LDR R1, [R0]
   BIC R1, R1, #0x04  
   STR R1, [R0]         
   MOV R2, #0x100000
delay2
   SUBS R2, R2, #1
   BNE delay2
   B main
```

Comment: "дело в неверных адресах" - скорее всего да.

Comment: Да, да вот бы кто пояснил какие адреса подходят. В разных методичках к, казалось бы, одному контроллеру разные адреса

Comment: Пользуйтесь документацией производителя. Найти её в Интернете не составляет никакого труда.